# Address to be used to access private ipaddress for AZURE resource from on-premise

Tags: azure-networking

I can see how we can make an AZURE database, say COSMOS DB, a private IP address with Private link, that is fine.

If you want to access that private link / IP address database from on-premise via site2site vpn, with a tool like Spotfire or Tableau, how do we specify the connection string that goes via the ExpressRoute or Site2SiteVPN? I cannot find any examples on that and how that occurs.

It must be basic, but I cannot see it.

**Update**

Looking at this: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-dns#on-premises-workloads-using-a-dns-forwarder

[image]

I get the impression that the name "azsql1.database.windows.net" would be the connection string I need?

Comment: Please be more specific. Instead "AZURE database" please specify which database you are using, see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/product-categories/databases/ for a selection.

Are you able to reach the VNET configured in your azure subscription from on-prem via [ExpressRoute](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/expressroute/) or [Site2Site VPN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/)
A better phrased question would increase the likelihood of a good answer.

Comment: @LutzWillek  added cosmosdb but SQL Server equally. Edited plus one more.

Comment: @LutzWillek Thx. I get the overall concept, but I am looking for what aspect of all that jazz that I should I use as the "connect string", using, say, Spotfire on-premise to access the cosmosdb? It seems all quite elaborate.

Comment: @LutzWillek  updated question

Comment: Yes of cause either the DNS name or the IP address of the private link endpoint. So according to the picture added, either `azsql1.database.windows.net` or `10.5.0.5`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Private Link allows to access an Azure Cosmos account from within the virtual network or from any peered virtual network. Resources mapped to Private Link are also accessible on-premises over private peering through VPN or Azure ExpressRoute.

Read [access from a virtual network](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-configure-vnet-service-endpoint) first to learn the basic knowledge. Make sure you configured an [Azure Private Link for an Azure Cosmos account](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-configure-private-endpoints).

By default, an Azure Cosmos account is accessible from any source if the request is accompanied by a valid authorization token. Trouble? Check [firewall for Azure Cosmos DB](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-configure-firewall).

You can connect by using the [automatic or manual approval](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-overview#access-to-a-private-link-resource-using-approval-workflow) method.

So according to the picture you added to the question, both `azsql1.database.windows.net` or `10.5.0.5` would be adequate.

When connecting to a private link resource using a fully qualified domain name (FQDN) as part of the connection string, it's important to correctly configure your DNS settings to resolve to the given private IP address. Existing Azure services might already have a DNS configuration to use when connecting over a public endpoint. This configuration must be overwritten to connect using your private endpoint. One way to archive this is to use Azure DNS as the DNS resolver - for example via configured DNS forwarder.

Comment: azsql1.database.windows.net will only resolve to the private link IP if you’re using Azure DNS as the DNS resolver.  From the public Internet’s point of view, it’ll return the regular public IP of the Cosmos DB instance.

Comment: Thanks @GregW for your comment - you are right! Initially I thought this restriction would be clearly enough described, as it was mentioned in the question and also in the documentation I linked. However, you comment demonstrated me that it was not the case, so I added a section to clarify it. Thanks!

Comment: Yes of course either the DNS name or the IP address of the private link endpoint. So according to the picture added, either azsql1.database.windows.net or 10.5.0.5.  I am wondering whether that is correct if I have 2 corporate accounts in AZURE set up exactly the same.

Comment: @thebluephantom it all depends on DNS resolution.  The only time azsql1.database.windows.net will resolve to 10.5.0.5 is on the VNET (or peer VNET) with private link and the private link zone is linked to the VNET.   Essentially, when you’re on that private DNS-linked VNET, the DNS resolution is as follows:  azsql1.database.windows.net will be a CNAME pointer to azsql1.private.database.windows.net, which resolves to 10.5.0.5.  You need a conditional DNS forwarder on the VNET for .private.database.windows.net to forward to 168.63.129.16 and your on prem DNS to use that.

Comment: @GregW   I think you should have answered the question! I am not sure the answer on 10.5.0.5 is in fact correct now. I think I have the gist, were it not I am wondering how Tableau knows which azure instance to use.

Comment: It’s more knowing how private DNS zones work with linking to VNETs and Azure DNS resolution.  At the end of the day, you can create any DNS entry in your on-prem DNS that points to 10.5.0.5 and it’ll work.  It just won’t update if that private IP changes (say, if you remove, then re-add the private endpoint).

Comment: @GregW Slight abberation my side, forgot the with DNS must be all unique, it happens